# Combine dataframes result with a DatetimeIndex index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe with random values at every minute.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,30,size=20), index=pd.date_range("20180101", periods=20, freq='T'))

df
                      0
2018-01-01 00:00:00  21
2018-01-01 00:01:00  21
2018-01-01 00:02:00  23
2018-01-01 00:03:00  18
2018-01-01 00:04:00   3
2018-01-01 00:05:00  11
2018-01-01 00:06:00   3
2018-01-01 00:07:00   4
2018-01-01 00:08:00   5
2018-01-01 00:09:00  25
2018-01-01 00:10:00  15
2018-01-01 00:11:00  11
2018-01-01 00:12:00  29
2018-01-01 00:13:00  22
2018-01-01 00:14:00   7
2018-01-01 00:15:00  13
2018-01-01 00:16:00  26
2018-01-01 00:17:00   7
2018-01-01 00:18:00  26
2018-01-01 00:19:00  15
```

Now, I must create a new column in the dataframe `df` that "reflects" the mean() of a window of 2 periods on an higher frequency(5 minutes).

```
df2 = df.resample('5T').sum().rolling(2).mean()

df2
                        0
2018-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-01-01 00:05:00  67.0
2018-01-01 00:10:00  66.0
2018-01-01 00:15:00  85.5
```

Here comes the problem. I need to "map" somehow the values of the "higher frequency" frame to the lower.
I should get something like:

```
                      0     new_column
2018-01-01 00:00:00  21     NaN
2018-01-01 00:01:00  21     NaN
2018-01-01 00:02:00  23     NaN
2018-01-01 00:03:00  18     NaN
2018-01-01 00:04:00   3     NaN
2018-01-01 00:05:00  11     67.0
2018-01-01 00:06:00   3     67.0
2018-01-01 00:07:00   4     67.0
2018-01-01 00:08:00   5     67.0
2018-01-01 00:09:00  25     67.0
2018-01-01 00:10:00  15     66.0
2018-01-01 00:11:00  11     66.0
2018-01-01 00:12:00  29     66.0
2018-01-01 00:13:00  22     66.0
2018-01-01 00:14:00   7     66.0
2018-01-01 00:15:00  13     85.5
2018-01-01 00:16:00  26     85.5
2018-01-01 00:17:00   7     85.5
2018-01-01 00:18:00  26     85.5
2018-01-01 00:19:00  15     85.5
```

I am using pandas `0.23.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
df['new_column'] = df2[0].repeat(5).values
```

with `5` being your resampling factor

Comment: your code seems faster. I think is better to just return a list of values instead of recreate the dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You can `pd.concat` both dataframes and `fillforward`

```
df3=pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1).ffill()
```

Comment: It works but i do not understand why, i mean, df and df2 have different index so how pandas can understand it?

Comment: @Dail They have  the same index. Just that some indexes are missing in the resample, which we fill forward from previous values... For ex,`2018-01-01 00:05:00` is present in both dfs. Concat works based on indexes....

Comment: so, are you telling me that resampling does not remove indexes? yes like the one you wrote it exists on both. basically it fills missing indexes of df2?

Comment: another question, can i assign the values to a new column directly?

Comment: @Dail `resampling does not remove indexes?` It removes indexes.  `one you wrote it exists on both. basically it fills missing indexes of df2?` Yes. concat  with same indexes https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html fill other values. `can i assign the values to a new column directly?` The result `df3` is a dataframe. So, Yes,You can assign values directly, just as with any other dataframe series..

Comment: @|'-'| wait... do you mean i should rename the column after fillforward right? can i not do it during the concatenation? or maybe i just need to set the name in df2 right?

Comment: @Dail `ignore_Index` or `keys` argument of pd.concat helps. `df4=pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1,ignore_index=True).ffill()`